# Tier price when adding product to basket - where is it calculated?

Tags: cart, quote

When adding a product to the basket, where exactly is the price that appears in the quote for each item calculated? (base, special, tier...)

My issue is this:

- I have a simple product with a tier price with it (qty: 1 and above, customer group: special)
- when I add the product to the basket, the base price is being added instead (the tier price is ignored) (customer is in the correct customer group)

BUT - I use 2 environments - dev and staging

- on my dev machine, all is working fine - product is added with the tier price - all fine it the quote (sales_flat_quote_item)
- on staging (where I have no access to the database), the base price is used

I am wondering if I missed any setting but can't think of any.

So my question is: **wherein the code is the best place to see/check how the quoted price is being calculated when adding new candidates to quote**?

using CE 1.7.0.0

Comment: Is your tier price lower as a regular price?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### RESOLVED

all right, after some code digging..

Looks like the whole process is done later **when saving the basket** on collectTotals:

- $cart->save() (where $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();)
- **quote - collectTotals()**
- product - getFinalPrice()

See debug trace below:

```
[0] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price::getTierPrice() : app\code\community\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product.php (653)
[1] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::getTierPrice() : app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price.php (164)
[2] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price::_applyTierPrice() : app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price.php (61)
[3] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price::getBasePrice() : app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price.php (80)
[4] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price::getFinalPrice() : app\code\community\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product.php (715)
[5] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::getFinalPrice() : app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Subtotal.php (115)
[6] => Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal::_initItem() : app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Subtotal.php (48)
[7] => Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal::collect() : app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Address.php (957)
[8] => Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::collectTotals() : app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote.php (1263)
[9] => Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::collectTotals() : app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Cart.php (464)
[10] => Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::save() :
```

The issue with the Tier Price not being used on the other environment is because of the wrong customer group on checkout (that is a different issue all together - basically when having a VAT check enabled, the group may be changed automatically on the checkout)

Thanks all if you have spent any time on this

Comment: Can you tell how you traced the execution..Thanks